# How can I build a footer page component like github for my app?

Tags: angular

I would like to build a footer page like the one on github for my app.

I have a footer component as follow:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-footer',
templateUrl: './footer.component.html'
})
export class FooterComponent {
   today: number = Date.now();
}
```

and here is the template :

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="m-container m-container--fluid m-container--full-height m-
   page__container">
    <li class="m-nav__item">
        <span class="m-footer__copyright">
            Copyrights &copy; {{ today | date: 'yyyy' }} MINEPAT, Mountain Metrics by 
            <a href="#" class="m-link">Mountain</a>  
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="m-nav__link">
            <span class="m-nav__link-text">About</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="m-nav__link">
                <span class="m-nav__link-text">Terms</span>
            </a>            
        <a href="#"  class="m-nav__link">
            <span class="m-nav__link-text">Privacy</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#"  class="m-nav__link">
            <span class="m-nav__link-text">Contact Editor</span>
        </a> 
        <a href="#"  class="m-nav__link">
            <span class="m-nav__link-text">Help</span>
        </a>
    </li>           
</div>
```

How can I build a footer page like the github one?

Comment: Ok, but where is the problem?

Comment: @FIL, I would like to improve this presentation so that it looks like Github's

Comment: And your question is referred to HTML markup, CSS styling or Angular fundamentals?

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
li {
  display:block;
  padding-right:10px;
}

.item-2 {
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li class="item-2">Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

If i understand you from your question you want to create something like this